# Convert void* to const void**

Tags: c++

In CPP I use a C library, one of the method needs a `const void **` as parameter.

In my class I have a property whose type is `void *`.

I tried to call the function by doing `function(&my_property)` but the compiler complained that it could not convert a `void **` to a `const void **`.

To fix this issue I used a const cast and did `function(const_cast<const void *>(&my_property))`.

I try to avoid casting as much as possible and I would like to know if there is a "clean" way to do that without using a const cast.

Comment: This function can provide you with a `const void *` (through assignment to your pointee), you want a `void *`. You have to pop off a `const` there to make the type system happy, but why do you want a `void *` in the first place?

Comment: @Quentin but why does the type system complain. We can do `T const* x = (T*) y` but not `T const** x = (T**) y`. Why is that?

Comment: const void** is non-constant pointer to const void*. Implicit constness can only be added on top level. You need to take address on const void*. If your property have void* type, then create local variable const void* ptr = my_property; and call function(&ptr); But if it is kind of output parameter, then things are a bit tricky...

Comment: OOH this is what I missed and couldn't remember... The const does not apply to the pointer but to the pointee...

Comment: @Timo suppose you could: `T const c; T* a; T const **p = &a; *p = &c;`, now the non-const `a` points to a const object without a cast.

Comment: @Quentin oof nice example, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper solution would be to turn `my_property` into `const void*`. Otherwise you might break a contract of `function`.

Answer (score 1):

Replicating your situation in a simple manner, let's say you have this code:

```
void function(const void **p)
{
    //...
}

int main()
{
    void *my_property;
    function(&my_property);
}
```

Using `const_cast` is safe, I don't think it's all that *unclean*, but you have alternatives, the best of wich would be to turn `my_property` into a `const void*`, suspecting that may not be an option, you may just use a `const void*` pointer to wich you would assign the original `void*`:

```
void *my_property;
const void *pp = my_property;
function(&pp);
```

The conversion is still there, but it's implicit.

As Quentin [very accurately pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66814399/convert-void-to-const-void/66814931?noredirect=1#comment118106921_66814399), this does not make a lot of sense, unless it's just to *shut up* the compiler.

Comment: if argument of function is output parameter, you'll get result in pp, not in my_property.

Comment: Well, `const_cast` itself is safe alright, but then you're on your own to make sure that you don't modify the pointee if it was actually `const` to begin with -- lest you get UB.

Comment: @KonstantinStupnik, that's true, but then you'd just reassign it.

Comment: @Quentin, yes, that is true, I assumed that that is not the case for the OP, but it's something to guard against, yes.

Answer (score 0):

If the library is expecting an array of arrays using a cast probably wont fix it, if you can't check the library source you can guess. A manual conversion is a safe solution.
Using `new_cast_a_to_m()` requires you to delete the array at some point but not the original array; `struct X` and the code aroud it is just for this example, `new_cast_a_to_m()` should work for you by itself.

```
#include <iostream>

struct X {
    int a = 0;
};

int c_foo (X ** x){
    return x[4][0].a;
}

template <typename V>
V ** new_cast_a_to_m(V * arr, size_t n){
    V ** nc = new V * [n];
    for(size_t i=0; i < n; i++){
        nc[i] = &arr[i];
    }
    return nc;
}

int main(void){

    X ** arr = new X * [5];
    arr[4] = new X;

    std::cout << "intended c_foo() -> " << c_foo(arr) << std::endl;

    X * brr = new X[5];
    X ** nrr = new_cast_a_to_m(brr, 5);
    std::cout << "casted c_foo() -> " << c_foo(nrr) << std::endl;

    delete [] nrr;
    delete arr[0];
    delete [] arr;

    return 0;
}
```